# TreeViewItem toggle doesn't move with child items

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, treeviewitem

[image]I need to move the toggle button with respect to the child items. it is not at all moving and coming with parent item. It is making confusion with parent and child items. here is my source code.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                            Padding="0,0,0,0"
                            MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" UseLayoutRounding="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush  Color="#FFCECEC6" Opacity="1"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid 
                              Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          ClickMode="Press" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger SourceName="Bd" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5A5A56" Opacity="0.8" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5A5A56" Opacity="1" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HoverBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FF5A5A56" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FF5A5A56" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

It placing both parent and child items in same manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve, however, change this part and it should work:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      ClickMode="Press" />
```

Note `Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"` part
Note that you might want to change `Margin`, or some other properties to change its position.